# Accessing sessions in the Laravel's AppServiceProvider file

Tags: php, laravel, session

I want to access sessions in the AppServiceProvider file in Laravel. To achieve this, I've created a middleware file and defined it in the kernel.php file. However, even after doing this, when I use the Log function in the AppServiceProvider file, the session value appears to be empty every time. I'm sharing my files and code below. Is there anyone who can assist me with this?
I've defined my LanguageManager file in the Kernel.php before and after StartSession as I read that this might help in a certain article. However, despite doing so, there hasn't been any change. I'm still seeing an empty value in my Log file.

Middleware/LanguageManager.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LanguageManager
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (session()->has('locale')) {
            App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageManager::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

AppServiceProvider

```
        $lang=session()->get('locale');
        Log::info($lang);
        if (!(session()->get('locale')) ) {
            session()->put('locale', env('APP_DEFUALT_LANG'));
        }
```

ChangeLang function for change to locale value

```
    public function changeLang(Request $request){
        session(['locale' => $request->lang]);
        return response()->json(['message'=>"Language changed succesfully"], 200);
    }
```

My code keeps entering the if statement in the AppServiceProvider, where it assigns the default value to the locale value. Because of this, I'm unable to send the updated value through the provider. What should I do?

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877799/laravel-global-middleware-cant-get-session , your middleware MUST be after StartSession, or you won't have access to anything in the session

Comment: On your AppServiceProvider.. do you use the register or boot method?

Comment: I defined it after StartSession but still the same and yes I'm using

Comment: [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33916580/laravel-session-variable-is-null-in-service-provider) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65871301/cant-get-session-variables-in-appserviceprovider) say that you can't use the session in the AppServiceProvider, because Service Providers are initialized before the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `\App\Http\Middleware\LanguageManager::class,` before the `verifytoken`. Order is required

```
'web' => [
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    .... 
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\LanguageManager::class,  // <-- Move it here
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

---

Second, set delay in the view load.

**In AppServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('*', function ($view) {
        $lang = session()->get('locale');

        Log::info($lang);

        if (!session()->get('locale')) {
            session()->put('locale', env('APP_DEFUALT_LANG'));
        }
      
        $view->with('lang', $lang);
    });
}
```

Comment: After going through these detailed steps, I managed to resolve the issue in my code successfully.Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this in your AppServiceProvider

```php
$lang = session()->get('locale');
Log::info($lang);

if (!(session()->get('locale')) ) {
    session()->put('locale', env('APP_DEFUALT_LANG'));
}
```

since Service Providers are initialized before the session, do the same thing on your LanguageManager middleware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setLocale(session()->get('locale', env('APP_DEFUALT_LANG')));

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: When I do this, the translates value does not come directly.

Comment: what do you mean with "does not come directly"?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense sorry. so it doesn't come

Comment: @MehmetÖzdemir register your `LanguageManager` middleware as the last middleware of the `web` group